# Play video from emulator sd card on VideoView - Android (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, video, xamarin.android

I am trying to display a mp4 video from my emulator on a VideoView and eventually display the thumbnail of the video using thumbnailUtils but I get "Can't play this video". I am assuming I am getting the path wrong since I can play the video from the Assets folder with:

```
Android.Net.Uri vid = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Drawable.SampleVideo1)
```

Using the device monitor I can see that my video is on /data/media/0/SampleVideo1.mp4 even though when I dragged and dropped the video on Genymotion it said that the file was copied on sdcard/Download. From other threads I saw people giving the path like this:

```
static string path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "SampleVideo1.mp4");
```

and I also tried with this way:

```
var vidPath = "/data/media/0/SampleVideo1.mp4";
videoview.SetVideoPath(vidPath);
```

What am I doing wrong and which is the correct way to set a path since I know that my video is on /data/media/0/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong and which is the correct way to set a path since I know that my video is on /data/media/0/ ?

It is possible that your file path is wrong, from your code I thought your file is saved in external storage(sd card), then the file path should be for example like this:

`/storage/0/Movies/your file`

But your file path is /data/media/0/, it's internal storage `Environment.DataDirectory`, and your app doesn't have permissions for reading and writing the file under the system media, I suggest to change your file path either to the external storage `Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory` or to the local data of your app for example to `FilesDir`.

Based on the title of your question, you file should be placed for example here:
[image]

And code for example like this:

```
var filename = "one.mp4";
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsoluteFile.ToString(), filename);
videoView.SetVideoPath(path);
videoView.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have placed my file where you suggested and my path now is: /storage/emulated/0/myVideo.mp4 but I still get: "Can't play this video". I have read/write permissions selected on my manifest file. Any ideas what is wrong now? And to double check, Environment should be Android.OS.Environment and not System.Environment right?

Comment: Turns out that it was my emulator (API 23), it plays fine on API 22